# How to run my program in mac terminal (Intellij)

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

[image]

I have the following Java program in Intellij and I cant seem to figure out how to run the program from my mac terminal (or export everything to run it on a different computer). Currently the only way I can run the program is if I press RUN in the IDE. I assume I need a .jar file but where do I go to compile that? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Packaging a Module into a JAR File](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/packaging-a-module-into-a-jar-file.html) and [may be this](http://lexsheehan.blogspot.com.au/2014/11/create-executable-jar-from-intellij.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer When I go to build, that Build Artifact is not clickable

Comment: From the Docs - *"Before packaging a Java module into a JAR file, you need to configure an artifact of the type JAR. This artifact can define the output of one or more modules."*

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you this worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your project settings in the upper right corner (or ctrl+alt+shift+s) and go to "Artifacts". Then add Jar -> From modules with dependencies
Choose your Module and your Main-class and Submit and apply the project settings

After that you can go to Build -> Build Artifacts -> Build
IntelliJ creates the jar inside the "out" folder in your project folder.

(This is for simple Projects. If your project is a bit more complex, you might need more settings.)

Answer (score 0):

@MadProgrammer: Before packaging a Java module into a JAR file, you need to configure an artifact of the type JAR. This artifact can define the output of one or more modules

Once I added the artifact and then build the artifact I am able to run the program via terminal